# ASP.NET MVC 3 Restrict API Access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, api, servicestack

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with a self hosted ServiceStack API that provides the data. After I added the API location path in Web.Config the API is callable by my code and works well:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The problem I have is that when the application is running the API is accessible via the browser - I can simply type http:\localhost:xxxx\api into the browser. What would be a good approach to restricting access to my self hosted API so that I can continue to call it within the MVC 3 application but prevent users from accessing the API via the browser?

Note that at some point in the future I will want to expose some areas of the API to make them publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: the [Authorization and Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) support built-into [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) is independent and decoupled from ASP.NET's Authentication.

You can generically restrict access to all your services by inheriting from a base class which contains one or more of:

- [Authenticate] - Only allow access to Authenticated users
- [RequiredRole] - Only allow access to users in the specified roles
- [RequiredPermission] - Only allow access to users with the specified permissions

Note: These attributes also work in your MVC Controllers that inherit from [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) or Controllers marked with the [[ExecuteServiceStackFilters]](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs) attribute.

You can inspect a MVC + ServiceStack demo that uses these attributes in the [Social Bootstrap Api](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) example project.

Another way you can generically restrict access is by registering a global [Request filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) which get executed on every request.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use a specific user for accessing the API:

```
<location path="api">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="api_user" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Then configure your API to be accessible only by the `api_user`. This way any other authenticated user in the browser won't be able to access this API. In your ASP.NET MVC 3 application you could create an authentication ticket with the given user before sending an HTTP request to the API.

Also notice that using the `<location>` tag in web.config to control authorization in ASP.NET MVC application is a very bad idea. The reason for this is that you are relying on some url (api). But ASP.NET MVC works with routes. So you should be using the `[Authorize]` or a custom authorization attribute to decorate the corresponding controllers/actions that you want to protect. This way your authorization is no longer dependent on your routing configuration.

Another possibility is to use a custom authoriza attribute and [implement an access token](http://blog.developers.ba/post/2012/03/03/ASPNET-Web-API-Authorization-using-Tokens.aspx).